# My search form does not seem to work

Tags: php, html

I want my search form to display users(username,firstname or lastname) from my database and display them as the user is typing like how facebook and twitter do but when i click search,nothing happens.Here are 2 parts of my header inc that deal with the search form,1st part:

```
 <?php 
  include( "Connect.php" ); 
  ob_start(); session_start();
  if (isset($_SESSION['user_login'])) {
  $user = $_SESSION["user_login"];
  }
else {
$username = "";
}

$output = "";
//Collect
if(isset($_POST['search'])) {
    $searchq = $_POST['search'];
    $searchq = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i","",$searchq);

$query = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE first_name LIKE '%$searchq%' OR last_name LIKE '%$searchq%'") or die("could not search!");
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    if($count == 0) {
        $output = 'There was no search results!';
        } else {
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
                $fname = $row['first_name'];
                $lname = $row['last_name'];
                $id = $row['id'];

                $output .= '<div> '.$fname.' '.$lname. '</div>';

                }
                }
                } 
?>
```

2nd part:

```
<form id="searchForm">
                <fieldset>
                    <div class="input">
                        <p>                          
                          <form action="header inc.php" method="post"> 
                          <input type="text" class="Search" id="search" size="35" placeholder="Search username,fullname or topic"/>
                          <label for="Submit"></label>
                          <input type="submit" name="search" value="Go" id="search" />
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    </form>
     <?php print ("$output"); ?>
```

Comment: form tag inside form tag!!

Comment: [Your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: I have added error reporting bt it's showin nothin

Comment: @Saty What do u mean?

Comment: @JayBlanchard i'll fix that later

Comment: Remove `<form id="searchForm">` from you code!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

invalid `action` name

```
 action="header inc.php"
```

you cannot use space in `.php` files

Edit the filename as headerInc.php and pass it in the form as:

```
 action="headerInc.php"
```

Comment: I have edited to header_inc.php bt it's not workin still

Answer (score -1):

I have changed your html code , just use it and it will start working. In your html there is hierarchy of **form** tag , I have added method post to first form and I have replaced the name of the text field by submit button name. In each post your data value was **"go"**.

I hope it will resolve your problem :

```
  <form id="searchForm" method="post">
        <fieldset>
            <div class="input">
                <p>                          
                <form action="header inc.php" method="post"> 
                    <input type="text" class="Search" name="search" id="search" size="35" placeholder="Search username,fullname or topic"/>
                    <label for="Submit"></label>
                    <input type="submit"  value="Go" id="search_button" />
                    </p>
            </div>
    </form>
    <?php echo $output; ?>
```

Comment: ,it's now workin!thanks a lot!do u mind if i ask u another question plz?

Comment: Why are you giving negative to me I have solved your problem dude

Comment: Please make it positive in place of negative

Comment: It's not me,i gave u a tick.This site has pple who like giving negatives

Comment: Ok no issue you can ask me another question

Comment: I dnt have enough reputation to give a positive or negative,sorry man bt it's not me

Comment: I have a homepage that is not displaying wat my friends update,it only shows mine n wat my friends post on my wall,here it is:

Comment: I do not understand what is the need for having a form within a form

Comment: $getposts = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE user_posted_to='$user' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10") or die(mysqli_error());
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($getposts)) {
                            $id = $row['id'];
                            $body = $row['body'];    
                            $date_added = $row['date_added'];
                            $added_by = $row['added_by'];
                            $user_posted_to = $row['user_posted_to'];

Comment: what would be the value of **$user**

Comment: @DimitrisPapageorgiou i get wat u r saying,i had not seen that bt I got an answer that worked

Comment: $user = $_SESSION["user_login"];

Comment: ob_start(); session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['user_login'])) {
$user = $_SESSION["user_login"];
}
else {
$username = "";
}

Comment: just tell me your table structure

Comment: Should i change it to user? bt if i do that will i be seeing my updates?

Comment: It has these fields:id,username,first_name,last_name,email,password,sign_up_date,activated,bio,profile_pic,friend_array,closed. in that order

Comment: i have asked you about **post** table

Comment: Sorry,it's: id,body,date_added,user_posted_to